# Adding a light in the garage

Tags: wiring

I want to add a ceiling light in my garage which already has 3 light bulbs wired. The plastic box and light bulb fixture have no screw or other place for ground. My romex has hot, neutral and ground wires. Should I just tape the ground wire in my new box and let it float (ie. unconnected)?

Comment: Are you sure the fixture itself has no place for the ground wire?  No green screw?

Comment: No screw anywhere

Comment: I take it the whole fixture is made of plastic then?

Comment: Yes, everything is plastic other than the metal screws for the hot and neutral wires

Comment: Everything is plastic except for the metal screws for the hot and neutral wires.

Comment: If this is the end run of the Romex, then just tape the ground wire and let it float in the box.  If this a middle-of-the-run box & fixture, then you need to continue the ground through the box using wire nuts to connect the incoming and outgoing wires per normal practice.

Comment: Does the fixture have a UL, CSA, or ETL mark on its label?

Comment: It is a plastic Leviton (mfg.) light bulb socket with UL/SA/NOM/AMCE stamps on the package.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have hot and neutral in a light fixture a ground wire in a plastic fixture is not required in the latest version of the national electric code 2017 and the preview version I have will not have a change for non conductive luminaries , lighting fixtures for the general public but more than light fixtures is covered. Plastic or non conducive fixture no grounding conductor is required ( the green or bare copper wire is not required even today.!